# UIButton center horizontally with word-wrap

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I have two UIButtons in container (UIView). Both of them have the same options (except button title) :

[image: UIButton's options]

But when I launch this app on iPhone 5S I get result as below :

[image: UIButtons on iPhone 5S]

My question is : Why first button have horizontally centered text and second doesn't ? I want both of them to center their titles horizontally.

Greetings,
Paweł

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you first button is centered only because it has shorter words in the title. If you set the title from the second button to the first button, you will se the same result.

You need to set text alignment through the code to make the title centered:

```
 [button.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: Thank you ! It helped. Now buttons looks like I want them to :) But instead of coding textAlignment I just put Custom runtime attributes in Interface Builder: keyPath="titleLabel.textAlignment", type=Number, value=1 (value of NSTextAlignmentCenter).